# how do you remove false error in typescript (error: TS2339)?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
var out = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0];
out.focus();
out.select();
out.selectionStart =1;
```

I'm trying to do this in my typescript file, but for some reason it gives me these errors

> ERROR in src/app/main/utilities/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts(29,9):
>   error TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>   src/app/main/utilities/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts(30,9): error
>   TS2339: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>   src/app/main/utilities/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts(31,9): error
>   TS2339: Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'Element'.

It is saying that the property does not exist, but it does. When I run this, everything works as it should but I have to do with a huge block of red text in my console which is annoying.

Comment: What type of element is it?

Comment: its an Input element

Comment: You just need to cast the object to a type that has the properties you want to call (i.e. the actual type the object it). Typescript can only do compile-time type checking, and still generates javascript that will work if the run-time object does have the property or method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to type cast your `out` variable to an `HtmlElement` in order for Typescript to know what methods and properties are available.

```
var out = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0] as HtmlElement;
```

You can also do something like this:

```
(out as HtmlElement).focus();
```

Or this:

```
(<HtmlElement>out).focus();
```

But then you'll have to re-assert the type every time you use `out`.

Read more about type casting / type assertions here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, however i had to change ``HtmlElement`` to ``HTMLInputElement`` as my element was an input

Comment: I had to change the letter case from `HtmlElement` to `HTMLElement` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know that the `Element` you are looking at is an `HTMLInputElement`, so it warns you.  If you are *positive* you are getting an `HTMLInputElement`, then you can use an assertion like @vincecampanale suggests.  Or, you can do something to convince the compiler, like using a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check:

```
function isHTMLInputElement(x: Element): x is HTMLInputElement {
  return (x.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT');
}

var out = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0];

// check that out is really an input element
if (!isHTMLInputElement(out)) 
  throw new Error("My life is a lie");

// from here on out, the compiler is convinced that out is an input element
out.focus(); // okay
out.select(); // okay
out.selectionStart = 1; // okay
```

The compiler is happy with the above code, because it uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to recognize that the code at and after `out.focus()` will only run if the type of `out` is `HTMLInputElement`.  Note that this does not suffer from the issue where you have to keep re-asserting that `out` is an `HTMLInputElement`.

Hope that helps.